# Alternative way to prove that the powers $\mathbb{C}^* \to \mathbb{C}^*, z \mapsto z^k$ and $\exp: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^*$ are covering maps

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function, lie-groups, covering-spaces

Prove that the power map, $\mathbb{C}^* \to \mathbb{C}^*, \: z \mapsto z^k$ and the exponential map $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^*, \: z \mapsto \exp(z)$ are covering maps using the fact that they are Lie-group homomorphisms.

I have seen proofs that the power map is a covering map before. But only as map from $S^{1}\to S^{1}$. And I have no idea how to use the fact that the maps are Lie-group homomorphisms.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: There are two ingredients to use: 1) surjectivity 2) group structure. The recipe is the following: determine the preimage of a small enough neighbourhood of 1. Then, determine the preimage of a small enough neighbourhood of any point.

Comment: @peterag yes of course that was a typo. Thanks

Comment: @Didier Okay so for the power-map I tried taking the open ball $B_r(1)$. But unfortunately I found no way to describe the preimage explicitly. For the second step: For any point $x \in \mathbb{C}^*$ I would shrink the ball $B_r'(x)$ radially until it does not intersect $0$ anymore. By step 1) the translated $B_'(1)$ is covered evenly by sets $V_1,...,V_n$. Then $B_r'(x)$ should be covered by $x^{1/k}\cdot V_1,...,x^{1/k}\cdot V_n$.

Comment: The idea is more or less to shrink the ball $B_r(1)$ so that its preimage is composed of $k$ disjoint connected open subsets  (each one containing a $k$-root of $1$). Since translation in a Lie group are homeomorphisms, this ensure that the primage of some sufficiently small ball around a point $z\in \Bbb C^*$ has preimage composed of $k$ disjoint open subsets. You are now left to show that each of these connected components are homeomorphic to a ball.

The same thing works for $\exp$ but the number of preimages will be infinite.

Comment: I think you are confusing $B_r(1)$ with $B_r(0)$. $B_r(0)$ you can decompose into k sectors each containing a k-root of 1. If you want to decompose $B_r(1)$ into k disjoint open subsets, each containing a root of 1. Say k = 4, then you would have to choose r >= 2, to include -1.  And no way to shrink that

Comment: No I'm not. I'm talking about the preimage of $B_r(1)$, not about the ball itself.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2455637/788724), but where the green rectangle is replaced by some small ball, and each blue region is replaced by some small potato (hoping you're not colorblind).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}$
Here is an outline of the proof that $f_k\colon z\in \C^* \mapsto z^k \in \Bbb C^*$ is a $k$-folded covering map:

1. Let $\alpha >0$ be a real number and $U = \{ re^{i\theta} \mid r >0, \theta \in (-\alpha,\alpha)\}$. Show that
   $$
   f_k^{-1}(U) = \bigcup_{j=0}^{k-1} U_j
   $$
   where $U_j = \{ re^{i\theta} \mid r >0, \theta - \frac{2j\pi}{k} \in (-\frac{\alpha}{k},\frac{\alpha}{k}) \}$.
2. Find $\alpha$ small enough such that all $U_j$'s are disjoint. You can find some inspiration [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk6gy.png), where the green region on the RHS is replaced by the whole sector $U$, and similarly for the blue regions (replaced by the $U_j$'s).
3. Show that $f_k$ maps $U_j$ onto $U$ homeomorphically.
4. For $\xi \in \C^*$, let $z$ be any $k$th root of $\xi$. Show that $f^{-1}(\xi U) = \bigcup_{j=1}^{k-1} zU_j$ and conclude.

The Lie group homomorphism's properties are used in 4: namely, translations in $\C^*$ (*i.e* multiplication by $\xi$ and $z$) are homeomorphisms.

The same reasoning applies for $\exp \colon \C \to \C^*$. The difference is that there will be infinitely many connected components in the preimage so that this is an countably-infinite covering. The outline is typically the same:

1. Find an open neighbourhood $U$ of $1$ in $\Bbb C^*$ such that $\exp^{-1}(U) = \bigcup_{j\in \Bbb Z} U_j$ where $\exp \colon U_j \to U$ is a homeomorphism and $U_j$'s are disjoint.
2. For $\xi \in \C^*$, find $z \in \Bbb C$ a preimage of $\xi$ by $\exp$ and show that $\exp^{-1}(\xi U) = \bigcup_{j\in \Bbb Z} zU_j$, and conclude.

These ideas do not come from nowhere, they come from simple drawings. In geometry / topology, sketches are good friends.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your help, Didier. The U is the blue object in the drawings from the other post and the $U_j$'s correspond to the green sectors right ? Should't r also vary a little ? Like $r \in (r_0,r_1)$. Or do you mean by $r > 0$ $\forall r >0$. I will try to fill in the formalilities in your proof tomorrow.

Comment: I've edited a bit but yes, $U$ is analogous to the green region and $U_j$'s to the blue regions. They are whole sectors (i.e $r$ can be any value in $(0,\infty)$), so that it is easier to handle, but you could have taken $r\in (r_0,r_1)$ for $U$. In that case, you should restrict $r$ to $(r_0^{1/k},r_1^{1/k})$ in the $U_j$'s.

Comment: Thank you, @Didier I got it :)

Comment: You're welcome! Side note: this is easier to show in polar coordinates since $f_k(r,\theta) = (r^k, k\theta)$ in this case. For the exponential map, this is easier to consider polar coordinates only on the RHS so that $\exp(x+iy) = (e^x, y)$